# React: why is one of my props yielding undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I am new to programming and trying to practice building a simple Full stack financial application using React, Express and PostgreSQL. I have a problem in the React part of my application, where one variable keeps returning `undefined` when it shouldn't.

I have three components, in order of hierarchy: `App` holding most of the logic, `Transactions` holding the list of transactions and offering the opportunity to add a new one, `List` holding the list of transactions, and `Transaction` being a single transaction.

Each transaction is an object consisting of an `id` (given by the database), `date`, `description`, `headerId` (linking it to a category in a separate table) and `amount`.

I am using a `useState` to hold these objects in a variable `transactions`.

Now here's the problem. I attempt to add a new transaction using this code in `list`:

```
function handleClick() {
        addTransaction(newDate, newDescription, newHeaderId, newAmount);
    }
```

which triggers this code in `App`:

```
  function addTransaction(date, description, headerId, amount) {
     Server.addTransaction(date, description, headerId, amount).then(res => setTransactions(prev => ([...prev, {id: res[0].id, date, description, headerId, amount}])));
```

which triggers the server to write it to the database.

The transaction is then written correctly to the database. However, the app then immediately crashes since for some reason, component `transaction` reads `undefined` for `headerId` of the new transaction and I am using it in an array function. All the order transaction variables can actually be read, and the correct `headerId` is shown for the transaction in the React Developer tools.

I have been searching for typo's, whether the props are correctly passed down, and all the like, but I can't seem to find the problem. I am curious to hear if anyone has a clue. Please let me know if you need more information or code.

As requested, here's the complete code for `transaction`, where the failure occurs at line `return headers.find(el => el.id === headerId).income;` because `headerId` is undefined.

```
import React from 'react';

export function Transaction({
    headers,
    showCorrectHeader,
    id,
    date,
    description,
    headerId,
    amount,
    removeTransaction,
    changeTransaction,
    lang}) {

    function isIncome() {
        return headers.find(el => el.id === headerId).income;
    }

    function handleChangeHeader(e) {
        changeTransaction(id, date, description, e.target.value, amount);
    }

    function handleChangeDescription(e) {
        changeTransaction(id, date, e.target.value, headerId, amount);
    }

    function handleClick() {
        removeTransaction(id);
    }

    return(
            <tr className='Transaction'>
                <td className='column-date'>{date.substring(8,10) + '-' + date.substring(5, 7) + '-' + date.substring(0, 4)}</td>
                <td className='column-description'><input type='text' value={description} onChange={handleChangeDescription}/></td>
                <td className='column-header'><select value={headerId} onChange={handleChangeHeader}>
                                <option key='-1' value=''></option>
                                {headers.map((header, i) => {
                                    return <option key={i} value={header.id}>{showCorrectHeader(header.id)}</option>
                                })}
                            </select></td>
                 <td className={isIncome(headerId) ? 'column-amount in' : 'column-amount out'}>{amount}</td>
                <td className='column-remove'><button onClick={handleClick}>&#215;</button></td>
           </tr>
     );
}
```

Comment: Please show a complete example of the code that is failing - how is `transaction` component rendered?

Comment: I added it to the original question.

Comment: Please show how `Transaction` is rendered - where do the props passed to it come from?

Comment: Fixed it with a workaround in the meantime...